# Neo4j : dynamically create node properties in foreach or as such, where the properties key/value are not known?

Tags: neo4j, cypher

Here's where I am stuck.

```
set t[x] = value[1]
```

The property value/key is known only at runtime.

Looking for dynamically setting property values post creation of node something like this:

```
match (a:User) 
with distinct(a.name) as property 
Match(b:Product) with property, b.Phone as value  
foreach(x in property  | 
         create(t:Test) set t[x] = value[1])
```

(note the `set t[x] = value[1]`)

Or

```
match (a:User) with distinct(a.name) as property
Match(b:Product) with property, b.Phone as value  
foreach(x in property  | 
     call apoc.apoc.create.nodes('Test', [x,value[0]))
```

(Note the `apoc.apoc.create.nodes('Test', [x,value[0])`)

Intension is to User Property's value becomes a Property for Test node.

Answer (score 3):

You can try the [`apoc.map.setKey`](https://neo4j-contrib.github.io/neo4j-apoc-procedures/#_map_functions) function to set the properties of the map:

```
WITH {} as props
WITH apoc.map.setKey(props, "name", "Jack") as props
WITH apoc.map.setKey(props, "surname", "Smith") as props
CREATE (N:TEST) SET N = props
RETURN N
```